# How to make a row in a list after clicking a buttom xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin.android

I want to make a fitness app which keeps your workouts. Im trying to make a list in which you can add your exercises and sets reps and weight but it didnt work. I tried to make a counter (sets) which increments every time the button is pressed but didnt manage to.
View

```
  
        <!-- Display ExerciseTypeGroups -->
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ExerciseTypeGroups}" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <!-- Display ExerciseType of the group -->
                        <StackLayout Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <Label Text="{Binding ExerciseType.Name}" FontSize="25" Padding="10" />
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <!-- Entry for Reps -->
                                <Entry Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="Reps" Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding NewExerciseReps}" />

                                <!-- Entry for Volume -->
                                <Entry Grid.Column="1" Placeholder="Volume" Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding NewExerciseVolume}" />

                                <!-- Button to add exercise to the group -->
                                <Button Grid.Column="2" Text="Complete" Command="{Binding CompleteExerciseCommand}" />
                            </Grid>
                            <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Add Exercise" Command="{Binding AddExerciseToGroupCommand}" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

ViewModel

```
 public ICommand AddExerciseToGroupCommand => new Command(AddExerciseToGroup);

 private void AddExerciseToGroup()
 {
    
     OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ExerciseTypeGroups));
 }
```

[image: Thats the current state of the app but when i click add exercise it does not add exercise]

Comment: May I ask can the ```AddExerciseToGroup```  or  ```CompleteExercise``` method be invoked when you click the button (you could add a breakpoint to check)?

Answer (score 0):

The Button is defined in `DataTemplate` in a ListView. Thus, the BindingContext of the Button is **not** the WorkoutViewModel. In this case, you should use [**Relative Bindings**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings?view=net-maui-8.0#bind-to-an-ancestor) or **x:Reference expressions**.

### Option 1 Use **Relative Bindings**

If you use **Relative Bindings**, you may refer to [Relative bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings?view=net-maui-8.0).

*For xaml page*

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Muscles_app.Views.WorkoutPage"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Muscles_app.ViewModels" 
             xmlns:Models ="clr-namespace:Muscles_app.Models" 
             BackgroundColor="White" x:Name="Workouts">


<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ViewModels:WorkoutViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>


    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ExerciseTypeGroups}" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <!-- Display ExerciseType of the group -->
                        <StackLayout Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="25" Padding="10" />
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <!-- Entry for Reps -->
                                <Entry Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="Reps" Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding NewExerciseReps}" />

                                <!-- Entry for Volume -->
                                <Entry Grid.Column="1" Placeholder="Volume" Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding NewExerciseVolume}" />

                                <!-- Button to add exercise to the group -->
                                <Button Grid.Column="2" Text="Complete" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ViewModels:WorkoutViewModel}}, Path=CompleteExerciseCommand}" /> />
                            </Grid>
                            <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Add Exercise" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ViewModels:WorkoutViewModel}}, Path=AddExerciseToGroupCommand}" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

*for code behind,* **Note**: **If you add BindingContext in XAML, then don't add it again in code behind.**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.BindingContext = new WorkoutViewModel();
    }
}
```

### Option 2 Use x:reference

You could also use x:reference Binding expression to achieve,

The only difference from **Option 1** is for XAML part.

*First we define the name for our page,*

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             ...
             x:Name="Workouts">
```

*Then make some changes for the button command binding,*

```
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ExerciseTypeGroups}" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <!-- Display ExerciseType of the group -->
                        ...
                                <!-- Button to add exercise to the group -->
                            <Button Grid.Column="2" Text="Complete" Command="{Binding BindingContext.CompleteExerciseCommand, Source={x:Reference Workouts}}" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Add Exercise" Command="{Binding BindingContext.AddExerciseToGroupCommand, Source={x:Reference Workouts}}" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                    </StackLayout>
       ...
        </ListView>

    </StackLayout>
```

For more info, you may refer to [Xamarin.Forms Relative Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings), [XAML Namespaces in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/namespaces)

Hope it helps!

Comment: If ```ExerciseTypeGroups``` is of type ```ObservableCollection```, then you don't need to ```RaisePropertyChanged``` after you add exercise.

Comment: I tried both. On the first one the is a error that says "Cannot resolve type "WorkoutViewModel"." after i added my view model to the code.
On the second one it cant  "find an objectr referenced in my page"

Comment: May I ask how do you set the BindingContext for the ContentPage?  Have you set it in code-behind, like ```this.BindingContext = new WorkoutViewModel()```?

Comment: yeah 
 public WorkoutPage()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     this.BindingContext = new WorkoutViewModel();
 }

Comment: Hello, I add more code to my answer to make it more clear. I have tested both of them. Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: I really appreciate the help but still have errors.  1 The namespace prefix "local" is not defined.
and 2 WorkoutViewModel is not supported in a Xamarin.Forms project.

Comment: Don't worry. I am sure we can work it out.

Comment: First, you may refer to [XAML Namespaces in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/namespaces).

Comment: <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Muscles_app.Views.WorkoutPage"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Muscles_app.ViewModels"
             xmlns:Models ="clr-namespace:Muscles_app.Models"
             BackgroundColor="White"
             x:Name="Workouts">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ViewModels:WorkoutViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
What am i doing wrong

Comment: I notice that you set ```xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Muscles_app.ViewModels"``` in ContentPage namespace, then for command binding, you should use  ```<Button Grid.Column="2" Text="Complete" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ViewModels:WorkoutViewModel}}, Path=CompleteExerciseCommand}" />```.

Comment: It works now. I really thank you for the help. I am trying to do this for a month now and you are a real life saver

Comment: So glad it helps!! I also edit my answer based on our cnversation, hoping to help others with similar questions. Thanks in advance!